# C# обертка для С++ статической библиотеки

Tags: c++, c#

Доброго времени суток!

Требуется сделать ActiveX на c# c использованием С++ библиотеки. Как сделать на с# ActiveX в сети много примеров хороших и разных. А вот как сделать DLL для использования на с# примеров не нашёл.

Используя подход №2, http://www.windows-tech.info/17/b11ab287a75874da.php approach #2, создал проект cppAx Visual C++ | Win32 | Win32, поставил галочки DLL и Export symbols. Добавил в проект заголовок статической библиотеки. Сгенерился следующий файл.

```
// cppAx.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cppAx.h"
#include "MyStatLib.h"
// This is an example of an exported variable
CPPAX_API int ncppAx=0;
// This is an example of an exported function.
CPPAX_API int fncppAx(void)
{
    return 42;
}
// This is the constructor of a class that has been exported.
// see cppAx.h for the class definition
CcppAx::CcppAx()
{
    return;
}
```

Дальше вроде нужно объявить экспортируемые функции из статической библиотеки. Но как не знаю. Даже если в таком виде компилирую и пытаюсь в другом проекте ссылаться на полученную DLL, то получаю

> A reference to XXX.dLL could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

В проект C# можно добавить ссылку на другую библиотеку, только если это сборка .NET или реальный COM-компонент. Судя по вашему описанию, это не так: в данном случае имеется обычная DLL.

Нужно те символы из C++, которые требуются в C#, сделать экспортируемыми напрямую или через обертки

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:somefunc=somefunc")

CPPAX_API void somefunc() {
    // Вызвать функцию из статической библиотеки
}
```

А затем вызывать их из C# с помощью P/Invoke

```
[DllImport("somelib.dll")]
static extern somefunc();
```

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить:
- как сделать пригодную для ссылки библиотеку?
- CPPAX_API int fncppAx(void) { return 42} - вроде бы как экспортируемая функция?
Может быть глупые вопросы но я с++ практически не знаю.

Comment: Чтобы библиотека была пригодной для ссылки, внутри нее должен содержаться COM, который правильным образом будет регистрироваться в системе при установке. fncppAx - да, это экспортируемая функция, правда, нужно проверить, что и def-файл содержит соответствующее определение.

Comment: В справке по def-файлам нашёл: Ключевое слово __declspec(dllexport) добавляет директивы экспорта в объектный файл, следовательно, отпадает необходимость использовать DEF-файл. В моём проекте его изначально не было. Нельзя ли по-подробнее о "правильном образе регистрации в системе при установке" ? Я что-то неправильно делают или нужны ещё какие-либо дополнительные движения? Я сейчас только про проект созданный с нуля с 1ой автоматом сгенерённой функцией fncppAx.

Comment: Если делать COM-компонент в DLL, то он должен создаваться по другом шаблону, вроде это MFC ActiveX или что-то вроде. Плюс перед использованием он должен регистрироваться с помощью regsvr32.exe. Но это все нужно, только если библиотека запоминает состояние, если это просто набор функций, то гораздо проще их вызывать через DllImport. Почитать можно здесь: [Calling Win32 DLLs in C# with P/Invoke][1], [Вызов неуправляемых функций из управляемого кода][1].

[1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx
[2]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms235282.aspx

Comment: 1. C вызовами Win32 через P/Invoke никаких проблем не вызывает.
2. Если посмотрите код из ответа ниже то там тоже не получится сделать ссылку на DLL в С#(A reference to XXX.dLL could not be added....) но тем не менее это не мешает через P/Invoke обращаться к функциям.
3.В моём проекте при вызове функции получаю ошибку:
Unable to find an entry point named 'fncppAx' in DLL 'cppAx.dll'

        [DllImport("cppAx.dll")]
        protected static extern int fncppAx();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = fncppAx();
        }

Comment: в продолжение моего коммента из Dependency walker-
CcppAx::CcppAx(void)
class CcppAx & CcppAx::operator=(class CcppAx const &)
int fncppAx(void)
int ncppAx
В колонке Entry Point стоят какие-то цифры.

Answer (score 1):

[Используем Unmanaged С++ код в .NET программах](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/net/101589/).

Comment: Скачал проект и при компиляции (только lib) получил - LNK2001: unresolved external symbol Create C:\...\Config.def и LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals. У меня VS2010. У Вас работает?

Comment: Компилятор говорит, что не может понять имя Create, потому что видит несколько функций с таким именем. MSDN рекомендует прописать декорированное имя функции, и рекомендует смотреть это самое декорированное имя с помощью DUMPBIN. Запускаем Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010), делаем cd в Debug, делаем "dumpbin /symbols main.obj /out:db.txt". Смотрим созданный db.txt, ищем там тот Create, который наш. Берем его декорированное имя (у меня "?Create@@YGPAXW4EObjectType@@@Z"), проверяем в той же командной строке, что все верно "undname имя", меняем в проекте Config.def так, чтобы там было Create=им

Comment: Я прочитал http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/3874211.flat.aspx после чего удалил def из проекта и убрал ссылку в свойствах проекта (танец с бубном). Всё заработало. Но дальше я не могу использовать это "интересное и весьма изящное решение" - у меня не стоит задача глубоко вникать в с++, без чего не разобраться в коде. Мне бы только "P/Invoke — очень просто, но не гибко".