# Исключение System.EntryPointNotFoundException

Tags: c++, c#

> Сделано вопросом из комментария в теме [выделение памяти под указатель в csharp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/31526/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B2-csharp) @ХэшКод

Спасибо, но возникает ещё одна проблема: выбрасывается исключение System.EntryPointNotFoundException. Приведу код:

В проекте на С# пишу следующее :

```
[DllImport("lib.dll",CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern void parse(String exp);
...
static void Main()
{
    String f= "1+2";  
    parse(f);  
    ...
}
```

В С++:

```
namespace lib {
    public class Parser
    {
        ...
        public :
        static void parse(char * function)
        {...}
    }
}
```

Пытался указывать в DLL Entry, но это тоже не помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка говорит о том, что в таблице экспортируемых функций не найдена требуемая. Надо ее туда добавить, например, так

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:parse=parse")
```

И кроме того, надо добавить перед самой функцией ключевые слова extern "C" (или макрос, который их включает).

Похожий вопрос: [C# обертка для С++ статической библиотеки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/19669/c-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8).